# vectors : What is the meaning of right handed system?

Tags: vectors

In a book, I read the following

"Having a fixed frame of reference, we introduce three unit vectors $\bf i, \ j,\ k$ along the directions of the $X, Y, Z$ axis respectively $\dots$ Note that every two distinct vectors in the set $\{\bf i$, $\bf j$, $\bf k$$\}$ are orthogonal. Therefore the system ($\bf i$, $\bf j$, $\bf k$) is called ${\bf orthogonal}$. Further, since all its elements are unit vectors, it is said to be an ${\bf orthonormal\ system}$. Note that $\bf i$ $\times \ \bf j$ is a unit vector perpendicular to both $\bf i$ and $\bf j$. Therefore $\bf i\ \times\ \bf j$ is either $\bf k$ or $- \bf k$. The first possibility holds when the system is right-handed, the second when it is left-handed. In a right-handed orthonormal system, we have the following cyclic formulas
$$
\bf i\ \times \ j = k, \quad j\  \times \ k = i, \quad k\ \times \ i = j
$$
$\dots$"$\\ \\$

My doubts are

1. Is the author assuming that the vectors $\bf i,\ j, \ k$ are along the positive direction of axes?

2.What is the meaning of right-handed system? It must have some meaning which is independent of $\bf i,\ j,\ k$.

3.Why have we made the concept of 'right-handed system' and 'left-handed system'? Is there any advantage of one on another?

Comment: An orthonormal ordered basis $(i,j,k)$ of $\mathbb R^3$ is said to be "right-handed" if $i \times j = k$.

Comment: Although the definitions given for a right handed coordinate system are perfectly correct, the intuition is lost. See [this](https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html).

Comment: "In a book, I read the following" - Could you please tell us the book? This would help to give a more adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. An orthonormal system $({\bf e}_1, {\bf e}_2, {\bf e}_3)$ is called *right-handed* if ${\bf e}_1 \times {\bf e}_2 = {\bf e}_3$ (equivalently, the same expression with $1, 2, 3$ permuted cyclically). We can extend the notion to general bases $({\bf f}_1, {\bf f}_2, {\bf f}_3)$ of $\Bbb R^3$ by declaring a basis to right-handed if $({\bf f}_1 \times {\bf f}_2) \cdot {\bf f}_3 > 0$ (again, we can freely cyclically permute the indices in this definition).
3. There is no *intrinsic* advantage to either convention. It *is* advantageous, however, for everyone to use the same convention, and we generally use right-handedness.

Comment: You are using cross product to define right-handed system. I think the concept of right-handed system is more fundamental it must be defined without cross product. More specifically, can I say that the vectors $\{\bf i,\ \bf j,\ \bf k\}$ form right handed system if we take the positive directions of X, Y, Z axes in right, up, up respectively?